# Unable to Import a database from Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to phpmyadmin

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Hey folks, the person I am buildling a website for decided to design their own database. They used Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to build it and such. Now that they are done with the database they exported it to a text file (Tasks -> Generate Scripts). Now when I try to import the file into phpmyadmin I get the following error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[master] GO /****** Object: Database [Butterbakers] Script Date: 02/15/201' at line 1
```

The database code is here: http://zamn.pastebin.com/Y3u7MpZ9

Comment: I would assume that a DDL script generated by Microsoft SQL Server is going to need quite of bit of modification before it can be successfully run on MySQL.

Comment: @JoeStefanelli the phpMyAdmin import feature has a MSSQL compatability mode, which looks like it should overcome this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With SQL Compare (http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) and SQL Data Compare (http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/) , you can synchronize different DB.

Comment: Will everything still be planned out correctly? Or will I have to tell them to re-make the database using a program that is designed for a MySQL database?

Answer (score 1):

phpmyadmin is for MySQL. 
Microsoft SQL Server is a different DBMS. 
Large parts of the SQL Syntax is DBMS/vendor specific.

The [MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) has a feature to "Create EER Model from existing Database".
This may be a try but you need a jdbc connection to the MS SQL Server and MySQL...

Converting DDL to a different DBMS is all but easy. And if you're done this doesn't guarantee that an probably already existing application is still working with the other DBMS.

Not switching DBMS and using the free [MS SQL Express](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=de&FamilyID=967225eb-207b-4950-91df-eeb5f35a80ee) could be an option.

First decide for a DBMS and restart form zero is surely the cleanest and less painful solution.

Comment: what would be my best option then? To edit the code manually or is there some kind of service that can help me with this? Maybe even an option in Microsoft SQL Server to export for a MySQL DB?